# C++ thread async for cv::Mat returning vector<rectangle>

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, asynchronous

I want to send captured frames to the different async thread in c++ , so my 6 frames can simultaneously process in threads and send back a vector

I couldnt succeed (I am scala guy new to c++)

here the func and the main :

```
std::vector<rectangle> frame_Face_Detection(cv::Mat& value)
{
    std::vector<rectangle> facesX;
    //do stuff
    return facesX;

}
```

in main:

```
std::future<std::vector<rectangle>> fn = 
  async(std::launch::async, frame_Face_Detection , &im_small);
```

it says :

> async (not matching function) error...

any help for a beginer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `std::ref` to pass object by reference to your function

```
cv::Mat im_small;
async(std::launch::async, frame_Face_Detection , std::ref(im_small));
```

Comment: Thanks jsut before I figured out it :) One last question :